# How to connect MSSQL from PHP 7, Plesk 12.5 installed on CentOS 7

Tags: php, linux, pdo, centos, plesk

My Plesk 12.5 installed on CentOS 7 and supporting multiple php versions in same time. I have successfully installed pdo_dblib driver for php version 5.4.16. Does anybody knows how to install similar driver for php 7.
I have PDO enabled on php7 and support PDO drivers mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite.
How I can add mssql.
I found this links 
[library I need php70w-pdo_dblib](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/) but how I can installed?
[question on the plesk site](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/mssql-in-plesk-12-5.335069/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for the help.
I have resolved my problem by simply connect MSSQL with ODBC diver, which is come together with PHP7
You need to make sure you have

/ etc/odbc.ini

```
[SomeName]
Description = " SomeName "
Driver = FreeTDS
Trace = No
Servername = TestServer
Database = dbname
UserName = username
Password = pass

[Default]
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.1
```

/etc/freetds.conf

```
[TestServer]
host =dbhostname
port = 1433
client charset = UTF-8
tds version = 8.0
```

And then in php

```
     $db = new PDO("odbc: SomeName ", " username ", " pass");
$sql = " select *…….”
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
```