# Using PHP MSSQL PDO with Plesk

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, plesk

My current Website Control Panel is PLESK Parallels, and i'm trying to use PDO MSSQL on my website.

I've searched the internet and i'm aware that the PDO dll needs to be in my php.ini file and such, but I keep reading different ways to do it all the time, using commands like YUM and i'm getting confused.

Can someone possibly, in plain, simple black and white instructions, explain the process so I can simply run code like this

```
try {
$hostname = "myhostname";
$port = myportnumber;
$dbname = "databasename";
$username = "user";
$pw = "password";
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
exit;
}
```

When I load my page where this command is located i get the error message

'Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver'

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @cmorrissey I disagree. Serverfault clearly states questions should not be about "working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel". That includes Plesk.

Comment: @icecub Plesk really has nothing to do with this question, its about installing the DLL and updating the php.ini file.  The question has nothing to do with the code provided.

Comment: @sam could you please provide your server operation system name and version, and PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

Example of installing `pdo_dblib` on CentOS-like OS for Plesk PHP `5.6`:

```
# yum install plesk-php56-devel
# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl download pdo_dblib
# tar -xzf PDO_DBLIB-1.0.tgz
# cd PDO_DBLIB-1.0/
# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/phpize
# ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php-config --with-pdo-dblib=./freetds

# vim pdo_dblib.c
```

On line #37 replace:

```
function_entry pdo_dblib_functions[] = {
```

with:

```
zend_function_entry pdo_dblib_functions[] = {
```

Save file and:

```
# make
# make install
```

you should see something like

```
Installing shared extensions:     /opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib64/php/modules/
```

Enable extension:

```
# echo "extension=pdo_dblib.so" >> /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/pdo_dblib.ini
```

Verify:

```
# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -m | grep pdo_dblib
pdo_dblib
```

Now sites in Plesk with PHP handler 5.6 will work with:

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

**Pay attention** for :

- [PHP DBlib PDO Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290310/php-dblib-pdo-issue)
- [How to connect MSSQL from PHP 7, Plesk 12.5 installed on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837068/how-to-connect-mssql-from-php-7-plesk-12-5-installed-on-centos-7)

Comment: Key words: error: unknown type name 'function_entry' Cannot find FreeTDS in known installation directories

Answer (score -1):

PHP PDO works in OOPS .

Hence in PHP PDO first you must create a database handler using PDO class which is already defined in PHP Library. which will work as object for your database queries.

When you connect your database using PDO Class than you are ready to play with your queries with the database handler which you got during PDO connection.

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

Here $dbh will works as database handler object for MySQL Queries Operations.

I have a personal blog for PHP PDO [here](https://developerscodes.wordpress.com/2016/11/22/php-pdo-implementation-using-class/) . Just go to reference and take a look how queries are working . Finally i would like to say it's very simple and secure.

Comment: Sorry, but it's definitely not related.